# resetting form fields except one

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reset all the form fields except one.

```
$(':input','#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, input[ignoreField]').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

How can I exclude inputs with "ignoreField" class?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -  `input[class=ignoreField]`

```
$(':input','#myForm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, input[class=ignoreField]')
```

Comment: Prefer the solution of FALCONSEYE, [class=ignoreField] is not jQuery valid, not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':input','#myForm').not('.ignoreField').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```